# Java files in src folder are missing in github repository

Tags: java, git, github

I am pushing an exiting project in github. 
Below are the steps I performed:

1. Go to the folder in file system
2. `git init`
3. `git add --all`
4. `git commit -m 'First commit'`
5. `git remote add origin https://github.com/joshiaatul24/spring-sec-basicauth.git`
6. `git remote -v`
7. `git push origin master`

The code gets successfully pushed to remote repository.

The issue is that the `src/` folder is empty folder. It doesn't have all the sub-folders and Java files inside it that I see on my local machine.

Can anybody please let me know why the `src/` folder files are not getting added to remote repository?

Comment: Please explain downvote

Comment: What do you see if you check the last commit using `git log -1 --stat`? Do you see any files added under the src folder?

Comment: Is your `src/` directory its own Git repository (does it have its own `.git/` directory)?

Comment: Yes, SRC folder has .git directory . But why does it get created at first place. I ran git init outside of SRC folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons include:

- `.gitignore` file (if it exists) has an entry that lists `src` and/or the filetypes in that directory (`*.java`)
- You were not at the top of the git repo when you typed `git add --all`
- the `src` directory has a `.git` directory under it
- You are viewing a different branch (a branch other than `master`)
- The operations succeeded but you are viewing the state of your repo for an earlier commit

Comment: Yes , SRC folder contains .git directory. Question is why did it get created since I ran git init outside of SRC folder.

Comment: Someone must have done something to create the .git directory. The commands you listed would not result in that directory being created.